# Converting LaTeX 2.09 template to LaTeX2e

Tags: pdftex

I have my university template to write my thesis, but it is old (written by Latex 2.09). I cannot add packages in it! wherever I add a package using \newpackage command I face error. As such, I cannot add figures since I do not have the required package! and so on.

Can anyone help me here? I highly appreciate your help ... I searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful. I tried making some changes in the document but each time I faced another error ... Unfortunately, my university hasn't updated this template.

This is the template:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-WE9fiW1148WkpiSWtpdEVZdjA

I have to say that I am not that professional with LaTeX, so my problem could be solved easily. I am using Overleaf.com as my LaTeX software. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use this one: http://tandysony.github.io/LaTeX-Thesis-Template-for-Concordia-University-Students/. It seems to be more up-to-date although based on the same basic code (which isn't great, but if it works...).

Comment: Thank you/ Finally, I wrote it somehow from scratch! Thanks a lot for your help.